# url hide only domain name show in url

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

my link is `www.example.com/#about`
I want to hide `#about` from url.
I have created a html page when I click `about` then scroll should go at about section on same page.but `#about` show in url. I want to hide `#about`. `#etc` my page working same but hide id after (#etc) only want example.com
not want a `www.example.com/#etc`.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayyub/3exsmtkg/5/) I have created. Hope this helps :)

JS File

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').on("click", function(e) {

    var scrollTo = e.toElement.text
    console.log($(this).text())
    var posTop = $("#" + scrollTo).offset().top;
    console.log(posTop);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('html, body').scrollTop(posTop);
    console.log(window.location);

  });
})
```